# Making sure that two entities don't overlap

Tags: c++, game-development

I made this snippet of code that makes sure that two entities can't overlap, but this is very verbose and it has 4 while loops, which will affect the games performance, how can I fix this?

```cpp
void Level::UpdateCollisions() {
  bool entitiesOnFloor[entities.size()];
  
  for(int entity = 0; entity < entities.size(); entity++)
    entitiesOnFloor[entity] = 0;
  
  for(int entity = 0; entity < entities.size(); entity++) {
    for(int entity1 = 0; entity1 < entities.size(); entity1++) {
      if(entity1 == entity)
        continue;
      if(entities[entity]->isStatic)
        continue;
      if(SDL_HasIntersection(&entities[entity]->dstRect,&entities[entity1]->dstRect) == SDL_TRUE) {
        if(entities[entity]->dstRect.y < entities[entity1]->dstRect.y) {
          while(SDL_HasIntersection(&entities[entity]->dstRect,&entities[entity1]->dstRect) == SDL_TRUE)
            entities[entity]->dstRect.y--;
          entitiesOnFloor[entity] = 1;
        }
        if(entities[entity]->dstRect.y > entities[entity1]->dstRect.y)
          while(SDL_HasIntersection(&entities[entity]->dstRect,&entities[entity1]->dstRect) == SDL_TRUE)
            entities[entity]->dstRect.y++;
        if(entities[entity]->dstRect.x > entities[entity1]->dstRect.x)
          while(SDL_HasIntersection(&entities[entity]->dstRect,&entities[entity1]->dstRect) == SDL_TRUE)
            entities[entity]->dstRect.x++;
        if(entities[entity]->dstRect.x < entities[entity1]->dstRect.x)
          while(SDL_HasIntersection(&entities[entity]->dstRect,&entities[entity1]->dstRect) == SDL_TRUE)
            entities[entity]->dstRect.x--;
      }
    }
  }
```

I can't think of anything else to fix this, I tried using a bunch of colliders but that was very buggy.

Comment: It seems to me that your algorithm might be unstable. E.g. when moving your object along Y or Y will make it collision-free with `entityX`, but at the same collide with `entityY`. And then again.

Comment: Anyway, this problem seems hard enough to look for some scientific paper describing multi-body collision avoidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to detect and respond to AABB interpenetration/collision. This has been a solved problem for decades. You can use the [Separating Axis Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem) to detect the collision as well as calculate how much to move the AABBs apart.

Some related links to help you out:

- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3841/2d-aabb-collision-response
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Ik2vowGcU0
- https://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-EsWKT7Doww

Comment: thanks a lot, sorry for the late response.

Comment: @LunarLandDev You're welcome. If this solved your question, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot.